# How can I use another rest client than jersey in an OSGi environment?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am currently trying to deploy an application to Apache Felix that can access an external rest webservice. I am using jax-rs for that and Apache CXF as the rest client, so my code looks somehow like this:

```
ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://my-endpoint.com/")
.path("path-to-api/")
.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
.get();
```

I have already deployed the Apache CXF rest client as an osgi bundle, but still I am getting the following exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder cannot be found`. The application works in a unit test and also when I directly use the implementation `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient` instead of the interface `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`. How can I use another rest client than jersey in an osgi environment?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution by myself. The problem was that I used the dependency `org.apache.aries.javax.jax.rs-api` instead of `javax.ws.rs-api`.